# Visual Studio 2015 Installation Not Starting Win 10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, windows-10

Installer stuck after first splash screen. This is what it looks like:

[image: Link]

It gives no error or anything.

Comment: Sounds like you should contact their support.

Comment: Check the Windows Application Event Log and Installation Event Log - if any went wrong, it will be logged there.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you hang on or blocked during the installation of VS enterprise 2015, please have a try with the following:

1. Disable your anti-virus and anti-spyware software, windows update up to date and clean up the %temp% folder, then run the installer as administrator.
2. When it gets stuck during installation, cancel it, but don’t uninstall. Go to the Control Panel--Programs and Features and select repair VS.
3. Go to Task Manager, see if there the task of VS and kill all, restart the computer, then re-run the installer as administrator.
4. Turing off the internet connection, then re-run the VS installer as administrator
5. Open the Task Manager in detail mode, look for a sub-installer process that showing 0% CPU usage and 0% disk usage, indicating it has died. Then just kill that process and the master installation will resume. Or open Task Manager in detail mode--> Go to the "Details" tab--> Right Click the VisualStudio Process-->Click on the "Analyze wait chain". You will see the name of the process which is responsible for the wait. Kill this process and the installation maybe process quickly.

If the above methods not work, you can use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder, then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.